AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'
I wanted to download quotes from MOEX. To do this, I used pandas_datareader. But it gives an error. Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem. I am attaching the code.
import pandas_datareader as pdr

f = pdr.moex.MoexReader('SBER', '2020-07-02', '2020-07-03').read()

Error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-18341a39c98f> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 f = pdr.moex.MoexReader('SBER', '2020-07-02', '2020-07-03').read()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5987         ):
   5988             return self[name]
-> 5989         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5990 
   5991     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'

Maybe there is a solution to this problem?
I looked at the documentation, but I didn't find a solution.

Try to use pandas 1.2.5 version. This works for me.
pip install pandas==1.2.5


The issue has been resolved. At least for me. I used to do this:
!pip install pandas

There was a mistake:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'

Then I did so and everything worked:
!pip install git+https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader.git

import pandas_datareader as pdr
import pandas as pd

f = pdr.moex.MoexReader('SBER', '2020-07-02', '2020-07-03').read()

